# Firebase: Getting a token via REST and using signInWithCustomToken

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am trying to understand Firebase custom auth methods using tokens, but the documentation is not all that clear to me. Before I tried playing with JWT generators, I wanted to check if there is a way to use the authentication response token to log in the web client via javascript:

1) First, in Bash:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[theapikey]' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"email":"[the-user-email]","password":"[the-user-valid-password]","returnSecureToken":true}'
```

2) Response:

```
{
 "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
 "localId": "<theresponse-localid>",
 "email": "<theresponse-user-email>",
 "displayName": "<theresponse-displayname>",
 "idToken": "<theresponse-idtoken-string>",
 "registered": true,
 "refreshToken": "<theresponse-refreshToken>",
 "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

3) So I copy the result into a JavaScript object:

```
var token = {
 "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
 "localId": "<localid-string>",
 "email": "<user-email>",
 "displayName": "<user-displayname>",
 "idToken": "<idtoken-string>",
 "registered": true,
 "refreshToken": "<refreshtoken-string>",
 "expiresIn": "3600"
};
```

4) I have tried each of these to try use that token for validation:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken() Error: ");
    console.log(error);
}

firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(JSON.stringify(token)).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken() Error: ");
    console.log(error);
}

firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token.idToken).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken() Error: ");
    console.log(error);
}
```

5) For each, I get this same error:

```
"Object { code: "auth/invalid-custom-token", message: "The custom token format is incorrect", stack: "" }"
```

I am obviously mistaken, but most documentation I read describes creating custom JWT tokens. I am afraid I do not understand yet.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: I was hoping to use the REST api to generate a token that I can use in JavaScript to authenticate a user with firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `signInWithCustomToken`, you need to create a JWT that is signed with your private key. The Firebase Admin SDKs provide that capability: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

That would run on your server and then you send the custom token to the client and sign-in with:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken() Error: ");
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bojeil, you are right. I did manage to write a JWT class to generate a token and I was able to use it in JavaScript. I used this article as reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

Comment: Cool, glad I was able to help.